# Intl.NumberFormat.formatToParts is not a function

Tags: android, react-native, intl

I am using the Intl namespace in **React Native** to do some currency and metric amounts formatting (W.h, etc)
When using the formatToParts method, everything works fine on IOS and also on Android debug mode. But in Android dev mode, I have the following error :

```
Intl.NumberFormat(_i18nJs.default.locale,options).formatToParts is not a function. (In 'Intl.NumberFormat(_i18n.Js.default.locale,options).formatToParts(value)','Intl.NumberFormat(_i18nJs.default.locale,options).formatToParts' is undefined)
```

In release mode, the screen on which I use this function makes the application crash

Code:

```
public static formatNumberWithCompacts(value: number, options: FormatNumberOptions = {}): FormatNumberResult {
    const isCompactForm =
      options.notation === NumberFormatNotationEnum.COMPACT &&
      (!options.compactThreshold || (options.compactThreshold && value > options.compactThreshold));
    const isCurrency = options.currency && options.style === NumberFormatStyleEnum.CURRENCY;
    options.currency = options.currency || I18nManager.currency;
    const isUnit = options.unit && options.style === NumberFormatStyleEnum.UNIT;
    const isPercent = options.style === NumberFormatStyleEnum.PERCENT;

    if (!isCompactForm) {
      delete options.notation;
    }
    // Format the given value with the given options
    const parts = Intl.NumberFormat(i18n.locale, options).formatToParts(value);
```

Comment: Could you share your code where you're calling Intl.NumberFormat.formatToParts?

Comment: Of course, done !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding to my index.ts all the polyfill imports indicated here:
https://github.com/web-ridge/react-native-paper-dates/releases/tag/v0.2.15

I also had to install each of this polyfills beforehand as indicated in the doc of Format.js : https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills